# Make @Html.TextBoxFor required for specific values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have @Html.TextBoxFor and I have made it required, But when i enter only space it could be saved empty. Now to avoid this I want to sent specific values that could be entered (about 30 values). If user enters a valued which is defined by me in only this case the for will be saved. Please help me to make this.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
<p>code:</p>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "form-control",  required = "required" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a collection at server end whitlist and can check if the entered code is in the list. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(YourModel model)
{
   List<int> whiteListCodes = new List<int>() { 123, 456, 789};


   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       if(!whiteListCodes.Contains(model.Code))
       {
          ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Please enter a valid Code");
          return View(model);
       }

       // write code to save code or model here
   }

}
```

Your model will look like:

```
public class YourModel
{
     public int Code { get; set;}
}
```

and your view would be strongly typed to this model.